# Angular asks for arguments if i dont use dependency injection

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I trying to load a service like this, without di

```
translateService = new TranslateService();
```

It asks for 9 missing arguments.
When I use it like this

```
 constructor(private translateService: TranslateService)
```

it doesn't need any of these arguments.
My question is where do these missing arguments come from when I use di?

Comment: Your `TranslateService` is not `@injectable` right ?

Comment: its ngx-translate , it's supposed to use like second one but I'm just curious, where all those missing arguments come from.

Comment: I get it now it uses `TranslateModule.forRoot()` to pass those arguments on `bootstrapApplication()` method in main.ts. After that I assume it uses same injected class in all project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your TranslateService asks for 9 arguments in its constructor and that is why you're getting 9 missing arguments. By creating the instance manually

```js
translateService = new TranslateService();
```

you are taking the responsibility to create and pass the dependencies to TranslateService but when you're writing this:

```js
constructor(private translateService: TranslateService)
```

Now you're telling Angular to build the instance of `TranslateService` for you and Angular will now use what it calls `Injector` to find out what dependencies `TranslateService` needs by looking into it's constructor, build all those dependencies and finally inject them into `TranslateService`'s ctor.

It doesn't matter whether you implemented `TranslateService` yourself or it came with a third party package, this holds true for all Injectables.

The only thing `TranslateModule.forRoot()` does is to provide services like `TranslateService` for registration at root level(thus creating singleton services) so that you can inject `TranslateService` anywhere in your application.